# How to disable the button when undoing all text?

Tags: java, android

I am using a simple library for undo and redo and works great but the only thing is that when I constantly click the undo button at the end of getting all my deleted text, it clears all my text. I don't want to clear all my text instead of after getting all my text by hitting undo button I want the undo button to disable.

here is the java for undo and redo I am using

```
 public class TextViewUndoRedo {

    /**
     * Is undo/redo being performed? This member signals if an undo/redo
     * operation is currently being performed. Changes in the text during
     * undo/redo are not recorded because it would mess up the undo history.
     */
    private boolean mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

    /**
     * The edit history.
     */
    private EditHistory mEditHistory;

    /**
     * The change listener.
     */
    private EditTextChangeListener mChangeListener;

    /**
     * The edit text.
     */
    private TextView mTextView;

    // =================================================================== //

    /**
     * Create a new TextViewUndoRedo and attach it to the specified TextView.
     *
     * @param textView
     *            The text view for which the undo/redo is implemented.
     */
    public TextViewUndoRedo(TextView textView) {
        mTextView = textView;
        mEditHistory = new EditHistory();
        mChangeListener = new EditTextChangeListener();
        mTextView.addTextChangedListener(mChangeListener);
    }

    // =================================================================== //

    /**
     * Disconnect this undo/redo from the text view.
     */
    public void disconnect() {
        mTextView.removeTextChangedListener(mChangeListener);
    }

    /**
     * Set the maximum history size. If size is negative, then history size is
     * only limited by the device memory.
     */
    public void setMaxHistorySize(int maxHistorySize) {
        mEditHistory.setMaxHistorySize(maxHistorySize);
    }

    /**
     * Clear history.
     */
   /* public void clearHistory() {
        mEditHistory.clear();
    }*/

    /**
     * Can undo be performed?
     */
    public boolean getCanUndo() {
        return (mEditHistory.mmPosition > 0);
    }

    /**
     * Perform undo.
     */
    public void undo() {
        EditItem edit = mEditHistory.getPrevious();
        if (edit == null) {
            return;
        }

        Editable text = mTextView.getEditableText();
        int start = edit.mmStart;
        int end = start + (edit.mmAfter != null ? edit.mmAfter.length() : 0);

        mIsUndoOrRedo = true;
        text.replace(start, end, edit.mmBefore);
        mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

        // This will get rid of underlines inserted when editor tries to come
        // up with a suggestion.
        for (Object o : text.getSpans(0, text.length(), UnderlineSpan.class)) {
            text.removeSpan(o);
        }

        Selection.setSelection(text, edit.mmBefore == null ? start
                : (start + edit.mmBefore.length()));
    }

    /**
     * Can redo be performed?
     */
    public boolean getCanRedo() {
        return (mEditHistory.mmPosition < mEditHistory.mmHistory.size());
    }

    /**
     * Perform redo.
     */
    public void redo() {
        EditItem edit = mEditHistory.getNext();
        if (edit == null) {
            return;
        }

        Editable text = mTextView.getEditableText();
        int start = edit.mmStart;
        int end = start + (edit.mmBefore != null ? edit.mmBefore.length() : 0);

        mIsUndoOrRedo = true;
        text.replace(start, end, edit.mmAfter);
        mIsUndoOrRedo = false;

        // This will get rid of underlines inserted when editor tries to come
        // up with a suggestion.
        for (Object o : text.getSpans(0, text.length(), UnderlineSpan.class)) {
            text.removeSpan(o);
        }

        Selection.setSelection(text, edit.mmAfter == null ? start
                : (start + edit.mmAfter.length()));
    }

    /**
     * Store preferences.
     */
    public void storePersistentState(Editor editor, String prefix) {
        // Store hash code of text in the editor so that we can check if the
        // editor contents has changed.
        editor.putString(prefix + ".hash",
                String.valueOf(mTextView.getText().toString().hashCode()));
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".maxSize", mEditHistory.mmMaxHistorySize);
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".position", mEditHistory.mmPosition);
        editor.putInt(prefix + ".size", mEditHistory.mmHistory.size());

        int i = 0;
        for (EditItem ei : mEditHistory.mmHistory) {
            String pre = prefix + "." + i;

            editor.putInt(pre + ".start", ei.mmStart);
            editor.putString(pre + ".before", ei.mmBefore.toString());
            editor.putString(pre + ".after", ei.mmAfter.toString());

            i++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Restore preferences.
     *
     * @param prefix
     *            The preference key prefix used when state was stored.
     * @return did restore succeed? If this is false, the undo history will be
     *         empty.
     */
    public boolean restorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix)
            throws IllegalStateException {

        boolean ok = doRestorePersistentState(sp, prefix);
        if (!ok) {
            mEditHistory.clear();
        }

        return ok;
    }

    private boolean doRestorePersistentState(SharedPreferences sp, String prefix) {

        String hash = sp.getString(prefix + ".hash", null);
        if (hash == null) {
            // No state to be restored.
            return true;
        }

        if (Integer.valueOf(hash) != mTextView.getText().toString().hashCode()) {
            return false;
        }

        mEditHistory.clear();
        mEditHistory.mmMaxHistorySize = sp.getInt(prefix + ".maxSize", -1);

        int count = sp.getInt(prefix + ".size", -1);
        if (count == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String pre = prefix + "." + i;

            int start = sp.getInt(pre + ".start", -1);
            String before = sp.getString(pre + ".before", null);
            String after = sp.getString(pre + ".after", null);

            if (start == -1 || before == null || after == null) {
                return false;
            }
            mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, before, after));
        }

        mEditHistory.mmPosition = sp.getInt(prefix + ".position", -1);
        if (mEditHistory.mmPosition == -1) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // =================================================================== //

    /**
     * Keeps track of all the edit history of a text.
     */
    private final class EditHistory {

        /**
         * The position from which an EditItem will be retrieved when getNext()
         * is called. If getPrevious() has not been called, this has the same
         * value as mmHistory.size().
         */
        private int mmPosition = 0;

        /**
         * Maximum undo history size.
         */
        private int mmMaxHistorySize = -1;

        /**
         * The list of edits in chronological order.
         */
        private final LinkedList<EditItem> mmHistory = new LinkedList<EditItem>();

        /**
         * Clear history.
         */
        private void clear() {
            mmPosition = 0;
            mmHistory.clear();
        }

        /**
         * Adds a new edit operation to the history at the current position. If
         * executed after a call to getPrevious() removes all the future history
         * (elements with positions >= current history position).
         */
        private void add(EditItem item) {
            while (mmHistory.size() > mmPosition) {
                mmHistory.removeLast();
            }
            mmHistory.add(item);
            mmPosition++;

            if (mmMaxHistorySize >= 0) {
                trimHistory();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Set the maximum history size. If size is negative, then history size
         * is only limited by the device memory.
         */
        private void setMaxHistorySize(int maxHistorySize) {
            mmMaxHistorySize = maxHistorySize;
            if (mmMaxHistorySize >= 0) {
                trimHistory();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Trim history when it exceeds max history size.
         */
        private void trimHistory() {
            while (mmHistory.size() > mmMaxHistorySize) {
                mmHistory.removeFirst();
                mmPosition--;
            }

            if (mmPosition < 0) {
                mmPosition = 0;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Traverses the history backward by one position, returns and item at
         * that position.
         */
        private EditItem getPrevious() {
            if (mmPosition == 0) {
                return null;
            }
            mmPosition--;
            return mmHistory.get(mmPosition);
        }

        /**
         * Traverses the history forward by one position, returns and item at
         * that position.
         */
        private EditItem getNext() {
            if (mmPosition >= mmHistory.size()) {
                return null;
            }

            EditItem item = mmHistory.get(mmPosition);
            mmPosition++;
            return item;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Represents the changes performed by a single edit operation.
     */
    private final class EditItem {
        private final int mmStart;
        private final CharSequence mmBefore;
        private final CharSequence mmAfter;

        /**
         * Constructs EditItem of a modification that was applied at position
         * start and replaced CharSequence before with CharSequence after.
         */
        public EditItem(int start, CharSequence before, CharSequence after) {
            mmStart = start;
            mmBefore = before;
            mmAfter = after;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Class that listens to changes in the text.
     */
    private final class EditTextChangeListener implements TextWatcher {

        /**
         * The text that will be removed by the change event.
         */
        private CharSequence mBeforeChange;

        /**
         * The text that was inserted by the change event.
         */
        private CharSequence mAfterChange;

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {
            if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
                return;
            }

            mBeforeChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                                  int count) {
            if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
                return;
            }

            mAfterChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
            mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, mBeforeChange, mAfterChange));
        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    }
}
```

and my buttons and activity

```
switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.undo:
            mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
            break;
        case R.id.redo:
            mTextViewUndoRedo.redo();
            break;
```

Comment: maintain a boolean variable which allows you to do only one time.

Comment: how? I am not getting where is the code after getting all my text back

Comment: you are going to one by one back text or getting a whole text one time on doing undo?

Comment: one by one. but when i get all my text and then click undo button it clears all my text. at that point before clearing all my text i want to disable undo button to prevent all my text from clearing

Comment: you have to make changes in your class which stops you one step before.

Comment: you are working with `onTextChanged` in acitivity if yes then you can deal with this method.

Answer (score 1):

Change a little in your getCanUndo() function as follows

```
 public boolean getCanUndo() {
    return (mEditHistory.mmPosition > 1); //set 1 in place of 0 here in case 0 refers to no text
 }
```

Now, in you onClick()

```
  case R.id.undo:
        if(mTextViewUndoRedo.getCanUndo())
            mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
        else
            ((Button)findViewById(R.id.undo)).setEnabled(false);
            //make sure to set this button enabled on text change.
        break;
```

Now in your onTextChange

```
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
            return;
        }
        //Add here--------------------------------------------------
         ((Button)findViewById(R.id.undo)).setEnabled(true);
        mAfterChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
        mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, mBeforeChange, mAfterChange));
    }
```

Comment: how can i set enable the button on text change?

Comment: But the problem here arise is when i undo through this it works but it did not get my text colors and highlighting background?

Comment: in onTextChange function inside your text watcher add this line - ((Button)findViewById(R.id.undo)).setEnabled(true);

Comment: He wants to undo not only plain text but also textcolor and highlighter he used with the text.

Comment: Hi @S Shah can you explain bit elaborately about your comment - did not get my text colors and highlighting background

Comment: I hope that updated answer is helpful. If so, you may accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

yours undo works should return before the last stage.

```
public boolean getCanUndo() {
    return (mEditHistory.mmPosition > 1); 
 }
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: replace (0 ... 18) ends beyond length 10

Comment: still deleting all the text

Comment: @SShah add code where you are implementing this functionality in activity.

Answer (score 0):

When user click the button you just disable the button and in on text change again enable the button

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.undo:
        mTextViewUndoRedo.undo();
        btnUndo.setEnabled(false);

        break;
    case R.id.redo:
        mTextViewUndoRedo.redo();
        btnRedo.setEnabled(false);
        break;
```

and in on text change

```
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                              int count) {
        if (mIsUndoOrRedo) {
            return;
        }

        mAfterChange = s.subSequence(start, start + count);
        mEditHistory.add(new EditItem(start, mBeforeChange, mAfterChange));
       btnUndo.setEnabled(true);
       btnRedo.setEnabled(true);

    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
}
```